# Single-Board Computer for ROS2

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear Community

We are considering building a robot consisting of several modules (drives, sensors, UI, etc.) that we aim to combine as nodes in ROS2. Main concern is size / footprint (as small as possible), real-time capability, EtherCAT or CANopen, ideally an onboard IMU, temperature-sensor, a few analog/digital IOs and Gigabit Ethernet. We would employ such units as simple I/O-bridge to more complex planning tasks / SLAM proecessing of vision-data.

What are the best SBCs for that?

We browsed quite a bit the web, but did not find the "silver bullet" yet. This is why we are very interested in your opinion on this!

Many thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/363206/single-board-computer-for-ros2/) by [Raphael](https://answers.ros.org/users/60790/raphael/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-10-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First thing coming to mind is a Raspberry Pi. In my opinion you would at least need your card to run an OS

---

Originally posted by [Vic](https://answers.ros.org/users/68202/vic/) with karma: 71 on 2021-01-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!
Currently I am experimenting with rpi4 and RevPi Core 3 ( which is a RPi3 with rt-patch). Main problem imho are differences between 32-/64-bit systems. Raspberry Pi OS is currently only 32-bit, although the 64-bit version is  already in beta. I had troubles running a standard Pi Camera "out-of-the-box", since some dependencies are not available as 64-bit, yet.
Best working solution for me was to combine it with docker. Using other 64 OS,like ubuntu server 20.04, kinda brought me to the same solution. I hope this helps. Cheers!

---

Originally posted by [SpecialSnwflk](https://answers.ros.org/users/69114/specialsnwflk/) with karma: 11 on 2021-02-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1